# Azure.Data.Tables querying only next record (limit/take 1?)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, .net-6.0

I am using the quite new NuGet package Azure.Data.Tables-package with .NET 6 with two Azure Functions. One function is writing some records to a table. The other function is timer triggered and should pick up only one record at a time. The next record is identified by a DateTime column called *Next*.

So I have some code like this:

```
var yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(-1));
Pageable<MyEntity> queriedEntities = TableClient.Query<MyEntity>(filter: TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"Next gt {yesterday}"));
```

Now I don't want the Azure function to pull all records to the memory while I only want to work with one record. In MySQL for example I would do it with LIMIT 1. ORDER BY *is not* required. It should only be *one* record for each run.

How do I add this limitation to the code sample above? Is it even possible? I read about *take* option, but I don't get it...

Comment: I'm not well versed in this library, but I believe it should be `TableClient.Query<MyEntity>(filter: TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"Next gt {yesterday}")).Take(1);`, that it, just add the take method at the end of your call.

Comment: You made me facepalm myself. Thanks, bro. I confused myself by my IDE, because the return type changes to IEnumerable so .Take(1) did not compile...

Comment: However, this would still pull all records and only take one from the result..., so not comparable with a true limit, I guess. I don't think, that .Take(1) will ensure a better Query-performance.

Comment: Take(1) is supported by the library, and provided it is called on a queryable should only bring one result. If it is fetching a thousand results and filtering in memory, it is probably treating as an enumerable source.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you always want the newest entry? Then you could for examle use the Unix timestamp - current datetime in ticks as your PartitionKey and just query 1 item without any filters.

Comment: Not the newest entry, but an entry that will be next according to a DateTime column.

Ortigas and your answer both work well. However, I would say the version with .Take(1) is more economical.

Answer (score 0):

To get just one item you can query like this

```cs
var entity = await tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter: TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"Next gt {yesterday}"), maxPerPage: 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Note: I'm using the System.Linq.Async package here.